# image as a background in GUI form Intellij

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I have a problem using GUI form in IntelliJ, I want to add an image as a background so the components will be on top of it.

It is possible to do it on Netbeans because I can use the "null Layout", but I can't use it in IntelliJ, does anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Comment: *"I can use the "null Layout", but I can't use it in IntelliJ"* The user can thank their lucky stars you have not figured out how to. `null` layouts start broken and never really improve. One way to achieve this is to override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method of a `JPanel` and paint the BG image immediately after the call to the `super` method.

Comment: The Q&A chosen to close this is just one of many (many) [possible duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+background+image). Please search in future.